# How to use block to get the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using cache in my application and have used a common method to fetch the key.

```
def cache_key(key, options = {}, &block)
  unless block.call.nil?
    Rails.cache.fetch(key, expires_in: 30.minutes, &block)
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

In the above example, I am trying to get the result of the block. If it is nil,I don't want to fetch the key and I return nil. In this case block is called twice so if i run this method, it generates two queries.

How can I simplify this better?

Comment: store result in a temp var?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an effective use of the cache store. The whole point should be that you should only call the block when it's needed. Why are you doing this, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: `block.call.nil?` invokes `block` - that's what the `call` method does. `Rails.cache.fetch` will also invoke `call` on `block` if `key` is not in the cache yet. This is why you're seeing the two invocations. Perhaps you meant to write `block.nil?`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def cache_key(key, options = {}, &block)
  value = block.call
  return nil if value.nil?
  Rails.cache.fetch(key, expires_in: 30.minutes) { value }
```

Comment: I think this might be what the original poster is trying to do, but I don't understand why anybody would want to do this. This is not caching anything.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is this:

```
def cache_key(key, options = {}, &block)
  options = options.merge(expires_in: 30.minutes)
  unless value = Rails.cache.read(key, options)
    value = block.call
    Rails.cache.write(key, value, options) unless value.nil?
  end
  value
end
```

This'll first try to read the cache. If the value is (`nil`, `false`), it'll execute the block. If the result of the block is non-nil, it'll write it to the cache. The value (either the cached value or the block result, as appropriate) is then returned.